# What are the Big-Oh complexities of these tasks?

Tags: big-o

I have the following question as part of my revision for a final exam:

```
For each of the following problems give the worst-case running time in
Big-O notation.

(i) Adding n numbers
(ii) Finding the minimum of n numbers in an unordered array 
(iii) Finding an item in a binary heap 
(iv) Sorting an unordered list of items using merge sort
(v) Finding the median (The value of a numerical set that equally divides
the number of values that are larger and smaller) of an array of sorted
items
```

Are my current ideas correct?

```
(i) This would be O(n) because you are adding n numbers.
(ii) This again would be O(n). You have to check every element in this list.
(iii) Not 100% sure here, but i assume it would be worst case O(n log n) as most things are with binary heaps.
(iv) This would be O(n log n)
(v) Again i am not sure on this, maybe O(log n) since the array is sorted so you only need to search half the values, essentially a binary chop.
```

Could anybody point me in the right direction if any of my answers are incorrect.

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (v) Finding the median (The value of a numerical set that equally divides
>   the number of values that are larger and smaller) of an array of sorted
>   items
>
> (v) Again i am not sure on this, maybe O(log n) since the array is sorted so you only need to search half the values, essentially a binary chop.

This one is O(1).  You are interested in the item that is in the middle of the sorted array (for N odd), or the average of the two "closest" to the middle (for N even).

Since the data is ordered, you can simply examine the one or two elements needed for the result.

Comment: Ah i see, so say i had an array of 11 elements i would know the median would be element 6. To do this i could ceiling the division of 11/2. If that makes sense.

Comment: For a zero indexed array of 11 elements, you would take the index 5.  If your array index starts at 1, it would be the 6th element.

Answer (score 1):

> (iii) Finding an item in a binary heap
>
> (iii) Not 100% sure here, but i assume it would be worst case O(n log
>   n) as most things are with binary heaps.

This is actually O(N) as it can be solved by a traversal of the binary tree the heap is built on.